# Links to headings in GitHub-Flavored Markdown that also work in PDF built by DITA-OT?

Tags: pdf, markdown, dita-ot

Is there a method of linking to a heading in the same GFM `README.md` ("intra-readme" link) that works in *both* of the following situations?

(a) When formatted as HTML by GitHub

(b) When formatted as PDF by DITA-OT with Apache FOP

That is, I want something like (both of the following methods work in GitHub, but not in DITA-OT-built PDF):

```
[Link to custom anchor](#custom-anchor)

[Link to auto-generated anchor](#heading)

... intervening content ...

<a name="custom-anchor"></a>
## Heading

...
```

I think the answer is "No", but I thought I'd ask.

Some issues:

- Auto-generated anchors, based on heading text, are incompatible: GitHub replaces spaces with hyphens (`heading-text`), whereas DITA-OT uses underscores (`heading_text`). It's occurred to me to write a DITA-OT XSLT override to change this behavior, but I'd prefer to avoid that.
- DITA-OT supports Pandoc-style header attributes; GitHub doesn't.
- DITA-OT Markdown processing generates a [topic for each heading](https://www.dita-ot.org/3.6/topics/markdown-dita-syntax-reference.html).

### Background to this question

For now, I am deliberately and exclusively using `README.md` files to document a GitHub repo. I am not, for example, using GitHub Pages. Most directories in the repo contain a `README.md` file. For now, the readme content is enough.

Some users like docs in PDF. For those users, I have created a DITA map that refers to all of the `README.md` files, and I use the DITA Open Toolkit (DITA-OT) with Apache FOP to format that DITA map to PDF, resulting in a single PDF file that consolidates all of the content from the multiple readmes. I have my own reasons for using DITA-OT rather than, say, Pandoc. While I appreciate there are other ways to generate PDF from Markdown, I'm interested in DITA-OT-specific answers.

I can link from one readme to another (`[Link text](subdir/README.md)`)—such links work in both GitHub-formatted HTML and DITA-OT-built PDF—but I can't figure out how to do "intra-`README.md`" links, hence this question.